# Angular pass in string from .ts file for (click) handler in .html file

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I am creating a list of menu items, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" (click)="item.handler">
    <div>{{item.label}}</div> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

and I want to pass in the function to use as the click handler from the ts file, like so:

```
constructor(){
    this.menuItems = [
      {label: 'HOME', handler: 'homeHandler()'},
      {label: 'VIEW', handler: 'viewHandler()'}
    ]
  }

  homeHandler() {
    console.log('homeHandler called');
  }

  viewHandler() {
    console.log('viewHandler called');
  }
```

The label works as expected, but the click functions never get called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(click)="item.handler()`: you need to call the function. Also, you want: `{label: 'HOME', handler: this.homeHandler.bind(this)'}`. You want to save a reference to the function, not a  string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler cannot be a `string`, and it is in your case. This should make much more sense:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" (click)="item.handler()">
    <div>{{item.label}}</div> 
  </li>
</ul>



constructor(){
    this.menuItems = [
      {label: 'HOME', handler: this.homeHandler.bind(this)},
      {label: 'VIEW', handler: this.viewHandler.bind(this)}
    ]
  }

  homeHandler() {
    console.log('homeHandler called');
  }

  viewHandler() {
    console.log('viewHandler called');
  }
```

notice how handlers are function objects now not strings and those are called from the view